# Error in cellForRowAt index path

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I get a return error in my function.

The error message is "Cannot convert return expression of type 'UITableViewHeaderFooterView?' to return type 'UITableViewCell'

```
import UIKit

class PhotosViewController: UIViewController {
    var photos = Photo.downloadAllPhotos()
    struct Storyboard {
        static let photoCell = "PhotoCell"
    }
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.dataSource = self
    }
}

extension PhotosViewController : UITableViewDataSource
{
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return photos.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier:
            Storyboard.photoCell)

         //error Cannot convert return expression of type 'UITableViewHeaderFooterView?' to return type 'UITableViewCell'
         return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: fixed the problem changed code in bottom to  let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: Storyboard.photoCell)
        
        return cell!

Answer (score -1):

I fixed the problem. Changed code in bottom to:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: Storyboard.photoCell)

    return cell!
}
```